# JSON to HTML Table Code

Tags: javascript, json, html, html-table

I'm attempting to extract data JSON results and then placing the data in to a html table, unfortunately I haven't had any luck so far and was hoping to get some pointers with what I have created so far.

I would also like the option to only show some of the JSON results, so excluding some of the data.

JSON Results Website = http://asc.thecoin.pw/index.php?page=api&action=public

Below is what I have so far which doesn't work :(

Html Code:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>Asiccoin (ASC)</h1>
<div id="id01"></div>

<script>
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "http://asc.thecoin.pw/index.php?page=api&action=public";

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        myFunction(xmlhttp.responseText);
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlhttp.send();

function myFunction(response) {
    var arr = JSON.parse(response);
    var i;
    var out = "<table>";

    for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        out += "<tr><td>" +
        arr[i].pool_name +
        "</td><td>" +
        arr[i].hashrate +
        "</td><td>" +
        arr[i].workers +
        "</td></tr>"
        arr[i].shares_this_round +
        "</td></tr>" +
        arr[i].last_block +
        "</td></tr>" +
        arr[i].network_hashrate +
        "</td></tr>" +
        arr[i].fee +
        "</td></tr>" +
        arr[i].payout +
        "</td></tr>";
    }
    out += "</table>";
    document.getElementById("id01").innerHTML = out;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Open console and read error message explaining why you can't to it. Then google "CORS javascript".

Comment: `http://asc.thecoin.pw/index.php?page=api&action=public ` returning a JOSN object not an array!

Comment: Json is returning only 1 object , will return more then one

Comment: No need to iterate through loop as _service_ is returning `object` not `array`!

Comment: also don't need to take array directly access your response by using . operator i have added answer please check.

Comment: Once you enable cors on your server, your code will work. There's nothing wrong with it other than that your markup is wrong. Make sure to fix all the HTML open tag and closing tag issues, and add `colspan='3'` where appropriate.

Comment: Additionally, I suggest you add all your code not in a function into a function. Then call that function inside `window.onload = function(){ yourStartFunction(); }` This would be much cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

As response is a JOSN object not an array, you don't have to loop it. Use this function:

```
function myFunction(response) {
    var arr = JSON.parse(response);
    var i;
    var out = "<table>";

        out += "<tr><td>" +
        arr['pool_name'] +
        "</td><td>" +
        arr['hashrate'] +
        "</td><td>" +
        arr['workers'] +
        "</td></tr>"
        arr['shares_this_round'] +
        "</td></tr>" +
        arr['last_block'] +
        "</td></tr>" +
        arr['network_hashrate'] +
        "</td></tr>" +
        arr['fee'] +
        "</td></tr>" +
        arr['payout'] +
        "</td></tr>";
    out += "</table>";
    document.getElementById("id01").innerHTML = out;
}
```

NOTE: Just to make sure everytime your `response` is a JOSN object or not. If it's returning `array` also then above method is not going to work for an array response. So check if `response` is an array or not by using `Array.isArray(response)` and if it an array loop through it as you have done above else use my logic.

Comment: `typeof response` will never return **array**

Comment: Thanks @RayonDabre! To check `response` is an array or object you can use: `Array.isArray(response);`

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to run through an array in `myFunction()`. But your JSON-data represents an object.

Try this for a quickfix of this problem: Change

```
var arr = JSON.parse(response);
```

to this

```
var arr = [JSON.parse(response)];
```

This will put your object (from `JSON.parse`) into an array, so `arr.length` will not be `undefined`, and you can build your table. This works, as long, as your JSON remains an object. If your response is an array, then your original code will work.

You can extend your conversion by using a simple alternative:

```
var arr = JSON.parse(response);

if (arr.length === undefined) {
    arr = [arr];
}
```

If you would like to exclude some of your data, you can just omit some of your code for handling that (just don't output it in the table). Or, if you have multiple objects in an array, returned to you, you will need a criteria to omit some of the datasets, e.g. (arbitrary)

```
for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i].workers <= 1) {
        continue;
    }
    //...
}
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Why to keep `unnecessary` for loop in code..It may create confusion and will be difficult to debug in some cases..

Comment: I changed to 'var arr = [JSON.parse(response)];' but unfortunately it didn't correct it.

Comment: @Rayon Dabre: We do not know for sure, that there is always just one object returned from the request. When there are more, there will be an array to run through.

Comment: I don't think your solution will work in that case...I feel it will create array inside array..

Comment: @Rayon Dabre: You are correct, that is why I extended my answer to engage that problem

Comment: @daygle: Probably 'response' is not what you expect. Can you check, if it respresents your JSON-string, by adding ``console.log(response)`` to your function.

Comment: @deepakb thanks, still can't get it to display any data - you can check it here http://hashrate.thecoin.pw.

Comment: @daygle: The first problem still remains. You are getting an error message from the Server, when you try to access it through Ajax. You might want to have a look at this: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/

Comment: @Guido Kitzing - so your saying no matter what I do I won't be able to work with my html example?

Comment: No, I am not saying that. But you need to solve the problem concerning your Ajax-request across different domains. There seems to be some solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource Basically your code with the adjustments I suggested will work, when you are getting your JSON response.

Answer (score -1):

i have direct access your response in variable because we can't get date from request.
this is work properly.

```js
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "http://asc.thecoin.pw/index.php?page=api&action=public";
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        myFunction(xmlhttp.responseText);
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlhttp.withCredentials = false;
xmlhttp.send();
   
function myFunction(response) {  
  out = "<table>";    
    out += "<tr><td>" +
        response.pool_name +
        "</td><td>" +
        response.hashrate +
        "</td><td>" +
        response.workers +
        "</td></tr>"
        response.shares_this_round +
        "</td></tr>" +
        response.last_block +
        "</td></tr>" +
        response.network_hashrate +
        "</td></tr>" +
        response.fee +
        "</td></tr>" +
        response.payout +
        "</td></tr>";         
  out += "</table>";
    document.getElementById("id01").innerHTML = out;  
 }     
</script>
```

```html
 
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Asiccoin (ASC)</h1>
<div id="id01"></div>
```

Comment: `jQuery` is not tagged and is not needed too!

Comment: Oh so your using the data rather than the html link? How do I make it work with the link?

Comment: @daygle in your code this is works fine you need to change in "myFunction" only..

Comment: @Ankit Kathiriya - I did change myfunction

Comment: if not then please provide jsfiddle for that i will work for that.

Comment: Oh Rayon Dabre is correct - CORS is disbaled on my server, this may be preventing any data from appearing.

Comment: I need to find out how to enable this now

Comment: you don't need to do that only "myfunction" in your code is replace with my code it works...

Comment: @Ankit: Your code works, because you are setting the JSON directly, instead of pulling it from the server via AJAX. But that is currently the main issure here. CORS is disabled on the server, so it will not work, as intended by daygle.

Comment: @Guido Kitzing - Yes  you are right that is CROS Domain problem.

Comment: Yeah I was about to say that

Comment: Anyone know a easy way to enable cors?

Comment: add XMLHttpRequest.withCredentials = false  in your XMLHttpRequest.

Comment: Ok I got it working! I added 'Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://hashrate.thecoin.pw"' to the sites-available conf then enabled headers in apache2.

Comment: @Ankit Kathiriya - Are you able to show me where to add XMLHttpRequest.withCredentials = false?

Comment: @daygle add xmlhttp.withCredentials = true. at the creation of Xml Http Request.